# redirect ip and port to subdomain using apache

Tags: apache-2.4

I am trying to configure my apache server so that my subdomain will have the same behavior as the main domain

With my main domain, when I type the IP address it goes to example.com and displays the correct page, but with my subdomain ex: subdomain.example.com it won't since for this case I got a different port (ex:9000 pointing to docker container)

but when I type ip:9000 it shows the correct page and the same thing when I type the subdomain.

how can I tell the server to display the subdomain instead of the ip:port

here's my main domain config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    Redirect / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and here's my subdomain config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPass / http://111.111.111.111:9000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://111.111.111.111:9000/
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   RewriteEngine on
   Redirect / http://subdomain.example.com
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =subdomain.example.com
   RewriteRule ^ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You are redirecting http to https but your config does not show a  reverse proxy configuration for https for your subdomain, only for http.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I through I explained well, I want when I type the ip and port in the browser it changes to subdmain.example.com, the same thing happen with my main domain I type the ip and the url changes to example.com

Comment: @GeraldSchneider forget about https for the moment i doubt that its what causing the issue, I just want to do the same behavior of my main domain with my sudomain, I type the ip in the browser and it will change to subdomain.example.com

Comment: It's not possible to do this with Apache. You need to configure this in your application server.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider then how it's working with the domain, with this line `Redirect / https://example.com` it works

Comment: When you connect without a port you connect to Apache. When you connect with :9000 you connect directly to your backend server in the container and **Apache is not involved**. So, if you want to redirect to your Apache you need to configure this in your backend server. Or don't expose it in the first place.